Sometimes ARP broadcast get drop if two ipvlan interfaces from same parent devices configured in same network namespace
Sometimes ARP broadcast get drop if two ipvlan interfaces from same parent devices configured in same network namespace. Is there any limitation from ipvlan to use mutiple ipvlan interfaces from same parent in same network namespace.
Anyone faced similar issue, what is the resolution for this problem
